# Spark write columns of array<double> to Hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With Spark 1.6, I try to save Arrays to a Hive-Table `myTable` consisting of two columns, each of type `array<double>`:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val x = Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0)
val y = Array(-1.0,-2.0,-3.0,-4.0)

val mySeq = Seq(x,y)
val df = sc.parallelize(mySeq).toDF("x","y")
df.write.insertInto("myTable")
```

But then I get the message:

```
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]]
              val df = sc.parallelize(mySeq).toDF("x","y")
```

What is the correct way to do this simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the actual structure you're going for looks like this:
x|y
1.0|-1.0
2.0|-2.0
3.0|-3.0
4.0|-4.0

For this the code you want is this:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val x = Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0)
val y = Array(-1.0,-2.0,-3.0,-4.0)

val mySeq = x.zip(y)
val df = sc.parallelize(mySeq).toDF("x","y")
df.write.insertInto("myTable")
```

Essentially you need a collection of row like objects (ie: Array[Row]). It'd be better to use a case class as mentioned in another comment as opposed to just the tuple.